# Dúvida em BeginTrans - RollBack - CommitTrans

Tags: visual-basic-6

Bom Dia,

Estou com algumas dúvidas relacionadas aos controle de Transações: BeginTrans - RollBack - CommitTrans.

Atualmente estava utilizando em VB6 e surgiu as dúvidas:
1 - Os controles de Transações quando realizo um RollBack, retorna estrutura de tabela? 
  * por exemplo: Executo uns DROP TABLE, CREATE TABLE em uma mesma Transaction, e ocorre algum erro, ao executar o ROllback, as tabelas excluídas são restauradas/ e as criadas são excluídas?

2 - Ao Abrir uma Transaction onde é executado todas as transações antes de persistir em banco(CommintTrans) ? Algum arquivo log?

Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ariel,

Nem todo comando permite roolback, você deve olhar na documentação do banco de dados que vc está utilizando. Por exemplo, em MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html

> CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE statements do not commit a transaction if
>   the TEMPORARY keyword is used. (This does not apply to other
>   operations on temporary tables such as ALTER TABLE and CREATE INDEX,
>   which do cause a commit.) However, although no implicit commit occurs,
>   neither can the statement be rolled back, which means that the use of
>   such statements causes transactional atomicity to be violated. For
>   example, if you use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and then roll back the
>   transaction, the table remains in existence.

Isso quer dizer que por padrão elas causam commit, mas pode ser contornado com a clausula TEMPORARY.

Para a segunda questão, desconheço logs de transações. A transação em si, consiste no salvamento de um estado do seu banco de dados, não haveria por que ter um log, pelo menos de meu ponto de vista.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito Obrigado Celso, Ajudou e muito. Estou utilizando o sql Server 2008, vou procurar a documentação.